# How to convert a php array of objects to javascrript objects?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object, morris.js

maybe any of you can help me with this,

I need to convert a php array:

```
array ("{ option: 'Option 1', value: 1 }", "{ option: 'Option 2', value: 1 }", "{ option: 'Option 3', value: 0 }");
```

to js so that he looks like this:

```
var data = [{ option: 'Option 1', value: 1 },{ option: 'Option 2', value: 1 },{ option: 'Option 3', value: 0 },];
```

so right now what I have done was to:

```
json_encode($array) //Array [ "{ option: 'Option 1', value: 1 }", "{ option: 'Option 2', value: 1 }", "{ option: 'Option 3', value: 0 }" ]
```

Can anyone provide any advice? In case it helps this is related with the Morris Charts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $myVar = json_encode($myArray) ; 
?>
```

Then pass the variable to you javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myJsVar = <?php echo $myvar; ?>
</script>
```

I do not know Morris charts.. but maybe you can add a service where you can grab dynamically the data from a distant server providing a data source in the config. In this case you could completely separate the php and your js script which would be much cleaner. 
Hence your php script is executed on server side before the js code.. it will replace the values in your code before js will use it.

Comment: Many thanks, what I've donme after that was convert this new array to a string and add the missing elements before the JSON.parse. I've also needed to add some extra quotes to the array as the parse kept failing.                                                                                                                                                                                                                        data = data.toString()
var data = '[' + data + ']';